# Create dynamic page and open it in new tab using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am creating an application in angularjs.
I need some functionality where

> I can show some dynamic data in html page and can open it in new tab
>    or something similar to it.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: when you open new tab, all your angular services will be re-created. If this still proper to you, just use window.location.href in your js code

Comment: Thanks for answering. I just found another way to do it.

I created a html page and on click event i just called a function in controller passing id as identifier. (I used $window to open it in new tab having URL of state discussed below).

Then i created a new state(ui-route) with ID as its parameter which is linked to my new controller for new tab functionality. And same id is  then used to fetch data from database and update scope.

 Thanks alot.